# Best method to put url in href for SEO

Tags: seo

if possible, I would like to know what is the best practies for SEO to put url in `<a href="">`

Method 1:
`<a href="/blog-1">`

Method 2:
`<a href="http://example.com/blog-1">`

Can you help me?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bots can interpret relative as well as absolute URLs and follow them.

I would prefer **absolute URLs** as we can govern what the urls are, rather than leaving it to bot to find out and follow through them. It also provides the flexibility of switching the protocols from **http** to **https://** even though the page is non secure or vice versa. Hope this helps.